# Subclass cannot create constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to create an application. Currently, I have an abstract class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class DB {

    private final String dbName;
    private final String dbServerName;

    public DB(String dbName, String dbServerName) {
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.dbServerName = dbServerName;
    }

    public String getDbName() {
        return dbName;
    }

    public String getDbServerName() {
        return dbServerName;
    }

    abstract Boolean pushDataToDB();
}
```

This abstract class should be used by the following class:

```
@Component
public class InfluxDB extends DB {

    @Autowired
    public InfluxDB(String dbName, String dbServerName) {
        super(dbName, dbServerName);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean pushDataToDB() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the error with the following error: Could not autowire, no beans of String Type found. I'm getting this error with the constructor's arguments for both dbName and dbServername. What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Well...do you have any beans of String type that can be autowired into the `InfluxDB` bean being created?

Answer (score 1):

use `@Value` to inject value from properties file or system variables. It typically has a format like `${database.uri}`

Answer (score 0):

The `@Autowired` annotation injects the types defined in the constructor, in your case, two Strings, and if you need this class to be `@Component` and still need this constructor, then you need to define Spring Beans to be injected.

I would create a `@ConfigurationProperties` class and inject it instead of multiple Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Autowired, it's not neccesary there.

Autowired is to call a Beaned object.

I recommend you this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire